# Tentei fazer meu programa em C abrir já em tela cheia, mas apareceu 'error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant'

Tags: c, codeblocks

Eu quero que o meu programa já abra em tela cheia quando eu clico pra rodar. Pesquisei se tinha como fazer isso e vi algumas recomendações para colocar esse código no começo do programa

```
# include <windows.h>

keybd_event(VK_MENU  , 0x36, 0, 0);  /// no meu caso aqui é a linha 6
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x1C, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x1C, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_MENU  , 0x38, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Não deu certo e ainda passou a aparecer esta mensagem de erro
`error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant`. Essa mensagem aparece 4 vezes para cada uma das 4 linhas (a partir da linha 6).

Aprendi C ano passado na faculdade e confesso que estou meio enferrujado, talvez seja um descuido simples que posso não estar sabendo, mas no meu caso estou só terminando um projeto que deixei pela metade, e que sem aquele código funciona sem nenhum outro erro ou aviso. Estou usando o codeblocks 20.03 com o GNU GCC.

Gostaria de saber principalmente como fazer o programa já abrir em tela cheia. Se tiver como fazer isso com ou sem esse pedaço de código pra mim tanto faz, desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código que você está utilizando deveria estar em um `int main()`, mas não é recomendável utilizar isso, pois você está manipulando o *teclado*(esse código simula que você está apertando teclas do teclado), logo se tentasse rodar esse código em um `SO` diferente do que foi projetado, não iria funcionar.

Para vocẽ conseguir fazer isso(obs irá funcionar apenas em `Windows` por precisa do `windows.h`) você irá precisar executar a *função* [`ShowWindow()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow)

Ela possibilita várias coisas, uma delas e *máximizar* a *janela*.

Para isso coloque esse trecho no `int main()`(no começo do código).

```c
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
   //seu código
}
```

Ou você pode fazer uma função que realiza isso:

```c
#include <windows.h>

void janelaMaximizada(){
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}

int main()
{
    janelaMaximizada();
    //seu código
}
```

[Caso queira mais detalhes tem essa resposta no `SOen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061401/how-to-make-a-c-program-run-maximized-automatically)

Comment: Ah obrigado, funcionou bem dos dois jeitos, e obrigado também pela explicação do trecho de código que enviei, não sabia exatamente oq ele realizava